# validates_format_of to exclude certain patterns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation

I want a rails model to exclude certain patterns: runs of two or more spaces.

`User.name = "Harry Junior Potter"` is valid, but `User.name = "Harry  Junior Potter"` is not (two spaces between Harry and Junior). 
This to avoid identity theft, where those two names are displayed the same (HTML compresses runs of whitespace).

In other words: Allowed is: `[0-9A-z_-]` and '`\s` only in series of one'.

My regular-expression is too poor to craft such a regexp, this is what I have (with a negative [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), but it does not match correctly.

```
 /([0-9A-z_\-])(\s(?!\s))?/
```

Note: a before_validation hook already strip()s all the elements, so spaces at begin or end of the string are not a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, `[A-z]` is an error.  It's equivalent to

```
[A-Z\[\\\]^_`a-z]
```

...and I'm pretty sure that's not what you had in mind.  You have to spell out the two ranges separately: `[A-Za-z]`.  But in this case you're also matching digits and underscore, so you can use `\w` like @Sjuul did: `[\w-]+`.  That makes your regex

```
/^[\w-]+(?: [\w-])*$/
```

Of course, that will match silly things like `-- - ---`, and it *won't* match a lot of real names.  I'm just answering your question about allowing only a single space between names.

Comment: I son't really understand what you mean with "and won't match a lot of real names". I deliberately left out accents and none ascii characters for now, to focus on the double-spaces issue. (first thin gmy app wil have to do, after this, is accept my own name, Bèr :)

Comment: That's exactly what I meant.  I just wanted to head off any comments (from anyone) about problems not related to whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it a lot easier just to replace `"__" with "_"` ? (Using underscores to show the spaces)
My Ruby isn't that fluent but it should be something like

```
User.name.replace!("  ", " ") while User.name.contains("  ")
```

Then you could use this regex to check for the rest

```
([\w\-]+\s?)+
```

Comment: A good route, indeed: compress all spaces into one. Then the validation handler can look for duplicates: "Harry__Potter" would then become "Harry_Potter", wich may already exist. Small detail: I cannot simply look for a literal space, since in UTF8 there are many forms of whitespace possible (including tabs, linebreaks and so on)

Comment: You can use `gsub` instead: `User.name.gsub!(/\s+/, ' ')`. That will convert other whitespace to spaces in addition to collapsing it.  By the way, TAB and linefeed are ASCII characters, so `\s` will match them.  There *are* a lot of non-ASCII whitespace characters, but they would have no business being in a name; I would just disallow them.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest an alternate route.. a very weird one in fact. If you are on a time crunch and would not bother having an extra column in your existing table then i would suggest creating a slug of the user-name. I know its an overkill for your problem. But i prefer doing my checks that way. Instead of checking the new user-name against the already stored one(and breaking my head over all those messy regexs), i just check the new slug against the stored slug(which by the way, handle all those messy regexs for you). You can check out **to_slug**: http://github.com/ludo/to_slug

Slugs are used primarily to filter out dangerous characters from URLs. Why not utilize the same for checking user-names? It handles unicode characters too.

This is not a direct answer to your problem. But i faced the same situation as you did and since i was on a time crunch i decided to use slugs.

A simple check in my console yields:

```
>> "Harry Junior Potter".to_slug
=> "harry-junior-potter"
>> "Harry  Junior  Potter".to_slug
=> "harry-junior-potter"
>> "Harry         Junior           Potter".to_slug
=> "harry-junior-potter"
>> "Harry(junior(potter))".to_slug
=> "harry-junior-potter"
>> "Harry_Junior_Potter".to_slug
=> "harry_junior_potter"
```

So, now if and only if the slug validates the user is allowed to store his name.

Comment: I like this idea. It allows me to store whatever the user inserted, but use the validated value I wish to use. This way, you can change validation in future and have it backwards compatible.

Comment: The only disadvantage of having to do this is to have an extra column in the database. It is just a matter of trade-off (time vs storage). If you have enough time on hand, use regex checking. If not use slugs. I personally stay away from regexs as much as possible. Still, if you plan to not use the above solution then i suggest checking out http://rubular.com. It makes it easier to test your regexs.